# RASA response is always null though intent is identified correctly

Tags: rasa

I am trying to build a simple bot using RASA which ,to begin with, just needs need to return simple text as response.

The content of the files updated are as below:

stories.md :

```
## path_1
* condition
  - utter_condition

## path_2
* pictures 
  - utter_pictures

## path_3
* elevator
  - utter_elevator
```

domain.yml :

```
intents:
  - condition
  - pictures
  - direction
  
responses:

  utter_condition:
  - text: "Let me get the details on the condition"
  utter_pictures:
  - text: "Ok, for more pictures here is the way"
  utter_direction:
  - text: "You want to know about the direction"
  utter_tour:
  - text: "about the tour"
```

RASA correctly identifies the intent, but always returns the following as the o/p of the response_selector:

```
"response_selector": {
    "default": {
      "response": {
        "name": null,
        "confidence": 0.0
      },
      "ranking": [],
      "full_retrieval_intent": null
    }
  },
```

Should it not be returning whatever "utter_" response that is configured in stories? How do I fix this?

Comment: I figured out that the stories.md was placed in the wrong directory!

Comment: Hey Indi! If you found the solution to your problem, it's helpful if you answer your own question, so that future searchers can find it easily

Comment: Alright - I'm on it.

Answer (score 1):

I found out a couple of reasons why this was happening

1. first time , the stories.md file was placed at a wrong location
2. the problem arose a second time because the domain.yml format was wrong

When you run

```
rasa train
```

make sure you don't have warnings like below :

```
/anaconda3/envs/rasa/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rasa/utils/common.py:363: UserWarning: Loading domain from 'domain.yml' failed. Using empty domain. Error: 'The provided yaml file is invalid. You can use http://www.yamllint.com/ to validate the yaml syntax of your file.'
```

As suggested  http://www.yamllint.com/  is very helpful with the formatting.